# Monitor multiple OneDrives and take action on file changes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, onedrive, azure-logic-apps

**Environment**

- OneDrive for Business (multiple across enterprise)
- Azure AD Authentication

**Business Challange**
Monitor various folders of different users's OneDrive (one folder for each user's OneDrive) and take action on file changes.

**Current Research**
Each user can use MS-Flow to configure which folder to watch and the action to be taken. However, this is very user dependent and prone to mistakes due to wrong configuration or steps bypassed.
Also since this is a manual configuration, business users may not be comfortable setting up all the different rules.

Is is possible to have a service running centrally which can monitor a set of folders (user id and folder id being provided) and take actions over it. Administrative authorization can be granted to the service to access folders across enterprise, as we do not want repeated grant requests by end users.

I have looked at Function Apps but it doesn't have a suitable connector. Also any binding to a resource required is manual and one per function (as its compile time). Also evaluated Logic Apps but unable to find a reasonable solution.
Have also checked the OneDrive SDK Csharp (https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp) but it only gives methods to consume OneDrive which is anyway available via the REST APIs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/)

**Other Probable Solutions** 
Create a windows service containing FileSystemWatcher, set to monitor the specific folder and take any suitable actions. Since the OneDrive will be mapped However this service will be required to be installed on each required user's machine.

Any ways to centrally manage the monitoring via any solution (FunctionApps, LogicApps, Custom code) is greatly acknowledged.

Can provide any specific aspect if required.

Comment: You should check out web hooks in the MS Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks. Not sure if you can listen to a specific folder, but you can definitely setup a listener for a user's onedrive.

Comment: Unfortunately, a wrong turn has already been taken.  It seems they're looking for a document workflow app.  The platform for that is SharePoint, not OneDrive.

Comment: No, we are getting files in a common folder (Azure blob) via web app, and that needs to get synced to configured user one drive... The container name will define the drives set.. Able to do this via function app and blob trigger. Now want to reverse sync onedrive to Blob but unable to find such a trigger which we can code against

Comment: @juunas posted another question specifically for webhooks as SO would treat the concerns to be different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899694/ms-graph-webhook-for-onedrive-returning-null-as-resourcedata